# Powershell with boolean parameter

Tags: powershell

It's so incredibly frustrating I cannot even print $bool value passed in

```
 function test($param1, $bool) {
   Write-Host "test: $($bool.ToString())"
 }

 test("", $true)
```

I got empty string for $bool, why ? this doesn't happen if I have only $bool parameter ?

Comment: In short: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
 If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.  
 See the linked duplicates for details.

Comment: In other words: `test("", $true)` -> `test "" $true`

Comment: In PowerShell, `[bool]` is a type. I would avoid using a type name as a variable name.